# Hibernate - save two objects in a single transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions

I have two classes as follows:

```
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="author_name")
private String authorName;

@Column(name="author_desc")
private String authorDesc;

//getters and setters
}
```

I also have a Book class as follows:

```
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="book_name")
private String bookName;
//getters and setters
}
```

I would like to save both objects in a single transaction, that is either save both or not save any one of them. I have written the following code for this:

```
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Author author1 = new Author();
        author1.setAuthorName("Author1");
        author1.setAuthorDesc("Author1 desc");
        author1.setId(1);
        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setBookName("Book1");

        session.persist(book2);
        session.persist(author1);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Excpetion while saving author");
        tx.rollback();
    }
    HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory();
```

The author table has a unique constraint on the author_name field. So when this code is executed two times, an exception occurs the second time. In such a scenario, I would expect no record to be inserted into the Book table as well. However, this does not happen, a record is inserted into the Book table even when there is an exception while inserting in the Author table.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/53647672 - cascade type persist and @Transactional

Comment: Thanks, the example you pointed out uses a Hibernate mapping. Can it be done without using a mapping and without Spring Transactional?

Comment: Try adding 
```finally {
   session.close();
}```
Tell me do you see `"Excpetion while saving author"` in logs?

Comment: Hello, I tried adding the finally block, but the problem still exists. Yes, the Sysout within the catch block is printed

Comment: Additionally try adding `session.clear();` after `tx.commit();` and in the catch block before rollback.

Comment: tried, still does not work. I think when save or persist hibernate methods are invoked, they insert the record immediately and not when the transaction is commited.

Comment: Could you provide running MVCE for example on GitHub? Database can be H2.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is rollback due to exception for example if you are using Spring:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { MySaveException.class, MyApplicationException.class })
public void method() throws MySaveException,  MyApplicationException { 
    ... 
    ... 
}
```

And inside this method try to save two entities if one of them fails rollback will start due to exception you will throw.

Comment: thanks for responding, but is there a solution that does not use Spring?